# Running a C++ program from any directory

Tags: c++, linux, bash, directory

How do I run a compiled C++ program from any directory just by typing my program's name in the terminal. I used g++ to compile the program. 
I have OSX Sierra installed on my mac.  It would be great if there was a way to do this in C++, but if not I'm open to any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your terminal has a list of paths it looks in to find programs. Put your program in one of those or [add the path it is in](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/).

Comment: I normally create a directory `$HOME/bin` and compile things with `g++ thing.c -o $HOME/bin/thing` and have `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` in my `$HOME/.profile`

Comment: Note that if you place the export command in your `.profile`, you will need to `source` it with `source $HOME/.profile` or restart your terminal.

Comment: @nwp: Or put a symlink to your program in one of those, or create a shell alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type a name into the terminal, the computer needs to know where to look to find a program with that name. Obviously, the computer can't try to look in every folder, so it only looks in a few preset ones.

In order to have your program run from anywhere, you need to tell the computer to look for programs in the place your program is. This is called adding a program to your PATH variable.

[Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) is a guide for adding a directory to PATH on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the path where the compiled binary resides to your `$PATH`:

```
$ export $PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/my/program
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to emulate windows behaviour you can set next path:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/proc/$$/cwd
```

This add to your search path your current folder, so you can execute any file on your current folder without prefixing path.